# Error with xelatex on macos

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, macos

I updated the Tex installation on macos and the following piece of code, which used to work, is not working any more

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
 
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Arial}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
Τεστ Test
\end{document}
```

The error I get

```
...
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-latex.lde))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-greek.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/xgreek-fixes.def)
! Use of \__prop_put_linked:wnnN doesn't match its definition.
<recently read> \xpg@alias@keyvals@greek@mono

l.149 ...s@values{greek}{variant}{monotonic}{mono}
```

Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/626#issuecomment-1947937535

Comment: Thanks @JosephWright. I re-installed TexLive and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Completely removing TexLive and installing again, solved the problem.

Comment: that sounds quite unnecessary. You could have used the backup system from texlive to revert the l3kernel update. Or simply predefine the prop until a fix is on ctan.